# configuring datastax cluster dynamically

Tags: cluster-computing, configure, datastax

I want to create a connection routine that does not include nodes which are down during time of connection, does not create pools to the node. If some node goes down in between, then it is automatically blacklisted from round robin. Is there a way to do so?

The whitelist policy starts by asking a bunch of nodes but does not dynamically change it (to my knowledge). I did not find a way to make "Host" object. I did not find a way to get up/down status through java code as obtained from nodetool utility - but then I'd like to do so without starting a session, just like nodetool utility does without going in cqlsh.

Comment: Have a look at the TryDiscover method here: https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp/blob/master/CassandraSharp/Discovery/SystemPeersDiscoveryService.cs#L86. The library is in C# but this method is simply calling CQL queries to do the node discovery. You can adapt this and make it run every once in a while to make it more "dynamic". As for the white/black listing nodes, again, this library is doing it but I'm not sure if there's an equivalent one in Java that does it. if not, you can again adapt the code in this project to do what you want.

Comment: Also, Up/down status is simply determined by connecting to the node. If you can connect, it's assumed to be up. If connection fails, the node is considered down. I don't think there's any other way to check it or at least I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the DataStax [Java driver](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/common/drivers/introduction/introArchOverview_c.html)? I'm guessing you are by your mention of the white list policy. The driver already does automatic node discovery and transparent failover.

If a node goes down, the driver will detect it and stop issuing queries to this node until it comes back up. If you are looking for different functionality can you elaborate?

Comment: The white list policy asks the user to specify a certain set of nodes. I don't even want to do that. I just want to give it all the nodes in cluster, and have it "white-list" only the ones which are up. If within the time that the selection is made and the cluster is initialized, any one of the nodes go down and exception is thrown due to connection pools not forming, I want it to do the exercise again. The idea is to code once and not worry any time later if some node is down by makes its way into the whitelist.